# Syntax error in SQL Server while making Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, order-by, dynamic-sql

### Scenario:

I have a table with 100M+ rows of data so I have created an index with something as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FIBaseVoterWithDeletedAt  
    ON dbo.base_voter (name_voter,home_street_address_1, home_address_city)  
    WHERE deleted_at IS NULL ;
```

Now when I execute the following code, it executed in less time:

```
SELECT id,
name_voter,
home_street_address_1,
home_address_city
FROM dbo.base_voter
WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
order by name_voter asc
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Now, I want to create this query as dynamic SQL as these parts `name_voter asc, 0 , 50` need to be dynamic and will be sent through the backend.

But, when I try to execute

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);  
DECLARE @params nvarchar(1000);  

SET @sql =  
     N'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1,home_address_city  
       FROM dbo.base_voter 
       WITH(NOLOCK)
       ORDER BY @sort_col @sort_dir
       OFFSET @offset ROWS
       FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY';  
SET @params = N'@sort_col nvarchar(100),@sort_dir nvarchar(10), @offset int, @limit int';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params,  
                      'name_voter','asc', 0, 50;
```

I receive error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@sort_dir'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
```

I am not sure but is it because I am passing column name as a parameter? Or is there some other thing. I just want that query to be executed while preventing from SQL injection and with minimal execution time.

I will be here if you need any further information.

Comment: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid object name 'dbo.base_voter'.`

Comment: you CANNOT use variables in ORDER BY. Your code now looks like `ORDER BY @sort_col @sort_dir` but it's not supported syntax

Comment: Check out [Conditional Order By](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by) for some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@marcello has the syntax right](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219744/1186), but another thing, to prevent SQL injection you can check the values of `@sort_col` and `@sort_dir` (since I assume those are coming from the user). The direction is easy:

```
IF LOWER(@sort_dir) NOT IN (N'asc', N'desc')
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Invalid direction', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END
```

Column names are a little more involved. You can just use constants to limit to the output columns from the query:

```
IF LOWER(@sort_col) NOT IN 
(
  N'id', 
  N'name_voter', 
  N'home_street_address_1', 
  N'home_address_city'
)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Invalid column', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END
```

Or you can make sure the column at least exists in the table, which would allow you to change the columns in the query without having to change the `NOT IN` list, and also to allow sorting by a column not present in the output of the query (even if that might not always make sense):

```
IF NOT EXISTS
( 
  SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.base_voter')
      AND LOWER(name) = LOWER(@sort_col)
)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Invalid column', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END
```

I wrote about this and other techniques in a two-part series:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)

Answer (score 2):

from the comments of [@sepupic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/124448/sepupic) and [@Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin), I put this together:

[conditional order by](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by)

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);  
DECLARE @params nvarchar(100);  
declare @sort_col nvarchar(20) = 'name_voter'
declare @sort_dir nvarchar(20) = 'asc'

SET @sql =  
     N'SELECT id, name_voter, home_street_address_1,home_address_city  
       FROM dbo.base_voter 
       WITH(NOLOCK)' + NCHAR(10) +
      N'ORDER BY ' + @sort_col + SPACE(2) + @sort_dir + NCHAR(10) + 
      N'OFFSET  @offset  ROWS ' + NCHAR(10) + 
      N'FETCH NEXT  @limit  ROWS ONLY; '

SET @params = N' @offset int, @limit int';

--print @sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, 0, 50;
```